# Slow rate (Rx) retrieving an attachment from Gmail with javaMail on Android

Tags: android, gmail, jakarta-mail

I'm using JavaMail libraries to access Gmail and I'm getting a slow rate (Rx) performance in downloading a compressed file attachment (1 MB):

[image]

As you can see, getting the attachment and write it into SD takes around 20 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
public class MailFile {
InputStream is;
String fileName;

public MailFile( InputStream is, String fileName) {
    this.is = is;
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public InputStream getIs() {
    return is;
}

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}}
```

Retrieving a message:

```
private List<MailFile> getAttachments(Message temp) throws Exception {
    List<MailFile> attachments = new ArrayList<MailFile>();
    Multipart multipart = (Multipart) temp.getContent();

    for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
        BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
        if (bodyPart.getFileName()!=null && (bodyPart.getFileName().contains(ZIP_EXT) || bodyPart.getFileName().contains(XLSX_EXT)))
            attachments.add(new MailFile(bodyPart.getInputStream(), bodyPart.getFileName()));
    }

    return attachments;
}

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity.getBaseContext());

        Properties props = new Properties();
        //IMAPS protocol
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        //Set host address
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", "imaps.gmail.com");
        //Set specified port
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
        //Using SSL
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false"); //this line solved my problem


        Session imapSession = Session.getInstance(props);
        Store store = imapSession.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", SP.getString("incomingMail", activity.getString(R.string.confIncomingDefaultValue)), SP.getString("passwordMail", activity.getString(R.string.confIncomingDefaultValue)));
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

        Message msgArr[] = inbox.search(this.searchTerm);
        //Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
        if (msgArr.length > 0) {
            Message msg = msgArr[msgArr.length - 1]; //only last message
            Object content = msg.getContent();

            if (content instanceof Multipart) //si és un correu amb attach
            {
                Multipart mp = (Multipart) content;
                for (MailFile f : getAttachments(msg)) {
                    if (f.getFileName().contains(XLSX_EXT)) {
                        new XLSXReader(f.getIs());
                        // msg.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
                    } else if (f.getFileName().contains(ZIP_EXT)) {

                        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                        writeToFile(f.getIs(),new FileOutputStream(f.getFileName()));

                        long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                        Log.d("Time", "Time " + duration + "ms " + duration / 1000.0f + " sec");


                        ZipperFolders.unzipFile(unzipPath, f.getFileName());
                        loadZipObjects(f.getFileName());
                    }
                }
                doToast(activity.getString(R.string.messagesReceivedOK));
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ((PrincipalActivity) activity).setDate(null, false);
                    }
                });
            } else
                doToast(activity.getString(R.string.messagesReceivedKO));
        } else
            doToast(activity.getString(R.string.messagesNoneMessages, SP.getString("incomingMail", activity.getString(R.string.confIncomingDefaultValue))));

        inbox.close(true);
        store.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        doToast(activity.getString(R.string.messagesConnectionKO));
    }
    return activity.getString(R.string.messagesReceived);

}
```

I've tried to use MimeMessage but the result it's the same. If I donwload the same file inside the Gmail app it takes 2 seconds!. What's happening? Is Gmail limiting my bandwith? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I've solved myproblem adding            `props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");` before declaring the Session object.

This is the resultant Rx:

[image]

From 20 sec. to 2 sec. unbelievable!!

Comment: If you read the data without writing it anywhere, how long does that take?  If you write data to the file without reading it from a message, how long does that take?  Does writeToFile use buffered streams?

Comment: See also the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#lgmsg).

Comment: I get the same results reading the data directly from bodyPart.getInputStream() or Buffering the stream, writing 1MB of data to SD takes less than one second and changing the fetchsize property has no effect.  But `props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false")` worked like a charm! Thanks a lot, I've found it following the fetchingsize hint.

Comment: Yes, that causes the entire body part data to be read in one call to the server.  That works great as long as you have enough memory for the data.